# Dense layer with more neurons than on input

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

What is the purpose of having a dense layer with more neurons on the output than it received on input?

Let's imagine we have a neural network in which the last layer has the size of 1. Does it make any sense to add a Dense layer to this network with output shape of, say, 128? If so, how does it work? Having a single neuron on input to dense layer intuitively seems nonsense to me, as every neuron in dense layer will only receive this single signal anyway.

Are there any advantages of architecture like that?

Comment: Assume ReLU activation and a quadratic relationship between the one input variable and the output. Do you see why the additional neurons can help fit the function to the parabola?

Comment: Do you mean, that with having more neurons, the layer can make some computations like "if the input is between 0 and 10 then return 5, if the input is between 8 and 12 then return 8" - in a super simplified words?

Comment: It’s something like that. We have a post on here somewhere about how ReLU fits curves. I don’t know where it is, but I think our mod Sycorax posted it. Perhaps someone else knows which I mean and can link you to it. // Perhaps a better example would be if you had to fit to an absolute value, rather than quadratic. Do you see how ReLU with two neurons gives you that? // You might be interested in the universal approximation theorem. It uses this fancy word from topology called “compact” which just means closed and bounded when we deal with the real numbers (Heine-Borel theorem says that).

Comment: Many thanks for your comments - I will google up the names and theorems you mentioned and hopefully I'll get some more insights on this topic :)